# show records after current time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-order-by

Actually I want some records from my database. There is a field `Time_From`. I just want to show only those records which are after `DateTime.Now()`.
 But it is not showing, it shows records before and after `DateTime.Now()`

```
Select * 
from mytable  
where Vehicle_Booking_Date= @Vehicle_Booking_Date 
       AND Time_From > @Time_From order by Time_From"
```

The table definition (from the comment)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mtblVehicle_Booking] 
(
  [Sno]                    [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Vehicle_Number]         [nvarchar](100) NULL,
  [Vehicle_Booking_Date]   [datetime] NULL,
  [Time_From]              [datetime] NULL,
  [Time_To]                [datetime] NULL,
  [Vehicle_Used_By]        [varchar](100) NULL,
  [Vehicle_Booked_By]      [varchar](100) NULL,
  [Cost_Code]              [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [Budget_Line]            [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [Purpose]                [varchar](20) NULL,
  [Destination]            [nvarchar](500) NULL,
  [Trip_Details]           [nvarchar](500) NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: can you provide your table structure?

Comment: If you change `Select *` to `Select *, @Time_From`, what values do you get for `@Time_From`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mtblVehicle_Booking](
 [Sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Vehicle_Number] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [Vehicle_Booking_Date] [datetime] NULL,
 [Time_From] [datetime] NULL,
 [Time_To] [datetime] NULL,
 [Vehicle_Used_By] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Vehicle_Booked_By] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Cost_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Budget_Line] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Purpose] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [Destination] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 [Trip_Details] [nvarchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all records whose Time_From is greater than current time and date is equal to specified date,

```
Select * 
from mytable  
where Vehicle_Booking_Date= @Vehicle_Booking_Date 
AND Time_From > now() order by Time_From'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what database you are using. But concept remains same. Just substract the other date time from current time. If it is greater than 0 it means that the given date time is greater than the current date time.

Sample SQL

```
Select * 
from mytable  
where Vehicle_Booking_Date= @Vehicle_Booking_Date 
AND DATEDIFF(Time_From,SYSDATETIME()) > 0
```

Hope this helps.